# Безопасность формы

Tags: php

На простом сайте есть форма, которая принимает данные и с помощью ajax отправляет их в обработчик (условный mail.php)
Вот каким образом формируется сообщение в письмо:

```
$message = "

<br> Дата и время: $date
<br> Почта клиента: $_POST[mail]
<br> IP адрес клиента: $thisIP
<br> Сообщение: $_POST[message]

";
```

По сути, никаких валидаторов нет, кроме формата почты. Можно ли отправить в эту форму какой-то вредоносный код, чтобы он выполнился в mail.php, например функцию unlink('index.php') ? Смогут ли через эту форму заливать шеллы/вредить сайту?

Comment: Сайту нет, а вот произвольный html-код внутрь `$_POST[message]` запихнут и ваш почтовый клиент его с радостью отобразит (впрочем, я не в курсе, опасно ли это)

Comment: Т.е. то что никак не валидируется сообщение, без разницы? туда никакой php-код не запихнуть?

Comment: php — не запихнуть, html — запихнуть, и степень опасности этого зависит от клиента, который будет отображать этот html